# How to obfuscate code in Vite's library mode

Tags: vite

I've built a project with Vite.  I started from the vanilla TypeScript template.  When I created a web page all of the JavaScript code was heavily minified and obfuscated.  I did not have to ask for this; it was on by default.  However, when I turned on Vite's library mode, my JavaScript is readable again.

Is there a way to make a **library** build **and** have it **obfuscated and minified**?

Answer (score 3):

Minification is purposely [disabled in `lib` mode for the `es` format](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/blob/8b77695/packages/vite/src/node/plugins/esbuild.ts#L326-L332) because it breaks tree-shakability of the output. Vite only obfuscates/minifies the non-`es` formats (e.g., `umd`), and there's no config to override that.